# Python JIRA rest api - Filter changelog

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I can read JIRA issue's change log in python like below

```
changelog_response = requests.get(self.JIRA_URL + 'rest/api/2/search?jql=key=' + key_value + '&expand=changelog&fields=""',                                                                            auth=(self.JIRA_USERNAME, self.JIRA_PASSWORD))
json_issue_changelog = changelog_response.json()
```

I am running the above code in `FOR loop` to read change log details for all JIRA issues.

**Objective:** I am reading change log to fetch all sprint transition details of the issue. Let's say, if issue was not completed in the assigned sprint, then it got moved to next sprint. so, issue had two sprints assigned. Similarly I have to find out for all issues through the loop

I am interested only on sprint details, but, change log would give me all details. Is there a way to filter JIRA change log rest api to read only sprint details? I tried to find, but, it seems like filter is not supported for change log.

Because of I run change log for all issues, script takes hours of time to complete.

Total # of issues in project is 50000. Each issue has an average of 15-20 change log, but issue moved only between two or three sprint. so, `20 change log iteration (max) * 50k issues = 1 million` . This iteration may get increased when more issues logged.

questions:

- How to filter JIRA change log rest api by `Field = Sprint`?
- If filter is not possible for change log, any other way to read sprint transition details directly? This has to be done only through JIRA rest api, not through any library

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've ever managed to do is to process the changelog from the newest to the oldest change and ignore changes older than a certain date. Otherwise you would need to create a new REST endpoint that selects the changeitems in the DB with a where clause to only retrieve the ones you want. Not an easy thing